# Split Css file into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following css code

```
header{
  color:#00F; 
  font-weight:bold
}
/* This is some comment */
body{
  font-size:11px;
}
```

I would like to split this into a multidimensional array like

```
Array (
  [header] => array (
    [color] => "#00F",
    [font-weight] => "bold"
  )
  [body] => array (
    [font-size] => "11px"
  )
)
```

How would I go about doing this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Use a CSS parser like https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Answer (score -1):

Parse it using regular expressions.

For the 'outer' block: `([^{])+{([^}]+)}`
Once you have the text inside each `selector {...}` expression use: `([-\w]+):([^;]+);`

For the actual code, use [preg_match(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: @alexn Sorry for being blind, my bad